# Redgate Sql Azure Backup Doesn't See Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-backups, redgate

When I am configuring Redgate's Sql Azure Backup tool to restore a database, it doesn't let me choose anything from my local Sql Express instance. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: You should contact RedGate, although I think this tool is deprecated. Have you tried an 'sa' account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done any testing on sqlexpress databases which may well be your issue. I've had to deprecate the product in favour of a hosted solution at http://cloudservices.red-gate.com. Perhaps you can try SQL Compare and SQL Data compare as SQL Azure Backup was based on the engines of those tools.

I wrote SQL Azure Backup so any questions just drop me a line.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I'm doing a huge database backup, translation, and restore in prep for launching a new version of app.

Comment: I've got the workflow working by using Redgate's tool to backup the production db, a custom BCP-based app I wrote to do the translation, and Sql Azure's Migration Tool to copy the translated db back to production.